# Excel stuck on IF AND OR

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been trying to figure this out for about an hour, but just can't understand how it works despite researching how to use the IF AND OR on Google.

Basically what I am trying to figure out is how to display this:

If the value in E4 is larger than $A$5 AND equal to or larger than $A$9 THEN E4/C3*100 BUT if E4 is larger than $A$5 AND smaller than $A$9 THEN E4/C3*100 WITH a MINUS (-) symbol in front of the displayed result.

I'm still learning how to use Excel, so this is a bit advanced for me. Could somebody explain this please?

Comment: After adding my answer I've realised that both results give `E4/C3*100` so surely you just need to check if `E4` > `A5`?  The second part is irrelevant as `E4` will always be greater, less or equal to `A9` surely?  And... should have read the answer by @Glitch_Doctor before adding this comment. :)

Comment: Just realized I left a very small but important details out. It should have been like this: If the value in E4 is larger than $A$5 AND equal to or larger than $A$9 THEN E4/C3*100 BUT if E4 is larger than $A$5 AND smaller than $A$9 THEN E4/C3*100 WITH a MINUS (-) symbol in front of the displayed result. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: What if E4 is not larger than A5?

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(AND(E4>$A$5,E4>=$A$9),
     E4/C3*100,
     IF(AND(E4>$A$5,E4<$A$9),
         E4/C3*100))
```

This `IF()` statement follows the exact logic you described in your question.

As you are looking for the same result for either scenarios though I would approach this with a single `IF()`:

`IF(AND(E4>$A$5,OR(E4>=$A$9,E4<$A$9)),E4/C3*100)` - as both results just want E4 to be >$A$5 we don't need to list this argument twice

But now we can see that the second argument will always be true, so you are in fact only looking for:

`IF(E4>$A$5,E4/C3*100)`

Comment: Get my vote for spotting the obvious before writing up a long answer...

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Haha, I was about to go in-depth when I spotted it :)

Comment: Just realized I left a very small but important details out. It should have been like this: If the value in E4 is larger than $A$5 AND equal to or larger than $A$9 THEN E4/C3*100 BUT if E4 is larger than $A$5 AND smaller than $A$9 THEN E4/C3*100 WITH a MINUS (-) symbol in front of the displayed result. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I guess a quick workaround would be `=IF(A5<A9,"-","") & IF(E4>$A$5,E4/C3*100)`.  This will return `-FALSE` if `E4<=A5` though.

Answer (score 0):

When you need complex IF-THEN statements, you're automatically going to end up with what we call "nested IF statements" because Excel is funny that way. Here's the equation you need:

```
=IF(AND(E4>$A$5,E4>=A9),E4/C3*100,IF(AND(E4>$A$5,E4<$A$9),-E4/C3*100,"HELP"))
```

The first IF tests your first equation, and if that fails, then we use the "If false" part of the first IF statement to develop our second IF statement. Note, you actually have 3 possible outcomes, but you only described two. Continue to nest IF statements until you have all scenarios accounted for. See my screenshot!
[image]

Comment: Just realized I left a very small but important details out. It should have been like this: If the value in E4 is larger than $A$5 AND equal to or larger than $A$9 THEN E4/C3*100 BUT if E4 is larger than $A$5 AND smaller than $A$9 THEN E4/C3*100 WITH a MINUS (-) symbol in front of the displayed result. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Simply add the negative symbol, as I've done here:
`=IF(AND(E4>$A$5,E4>=A9),E4/C3*100,IF(AND(E4>$A$5,E4<$A$9),-E4/C3*100,"HELP"))`

Comment: @ACMarston I've edited the post as well. Please be sure to hit the checkmark next to the best answer when you're done!

Answer (score 0):

[AND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/and-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9) takes a number of conditions and returns TRUE if all the conditions equate to TRUE.

You have two `AND` statements in your formula:

> If the value in E4 is larger than $A$5 AND equal to or larger than $A$9

This is written as `AND($E$4>$A$5,$E$4>=$A$9)` and will return TRUE or FALSE.

Your second `AND` statement is:

> if E4 is larger than $A$5 AND smaller than $A$9

This is written as `AND($E$4>$A$5,$E$4<$A$9)` and will return TRUE or FALSE.

---

The [IF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) function will return one of two answers based on a comparison returning TRUE or FALSE (such as the `AND` statements).

So the `IF` function is built as `=IF(Comparison, Result if TRUE, Result if FALSE)`.

---

Your comparison needs two `IF` functions so that FALSE is returned if E4 is smaller than A5.

`=IF(Comparison_1, Result if TRUE, IF(Comparison_2, Result if TRUE, Result if FALSE))`

Using your conditions this will be written as (replace the last FALSE with what you want to happen if no conditions are met):

```
=IF(AND($E$4>$A$5,$E$4>=$A$9),$E$4/$C$3*100,IF(AND($E$4>$A$5,$E$4<$A$9),$E$4/$C$3*100, FALSE))
```